# Performance of multi-column MySQL indexes when using only one column in a query

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing

I have a query on my database as such:

```
SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE user_id = ? AND dated_on = ?
```

I have added an index to the table on both the `user_id` and `dated_on` columns.  When I inspect the indexes using `SHOW INDEXES FROM expenses`, there are two lines -- one with a `seq_in_index` value of 1, the other with a `seq_in_index` value of 2.

My question is, if I then submit a query which uses only one of the two WHERE clauses, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE user_id = ?
```

Is there any benefit to creating another index which solely indexes the `user_id` column, or will the `user_id`/`dated_on` index described above be used just as efficiently?

Finally, how about if use the query:

```
SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE dated_on = ?
```

How does the `seq_in_index` value of 2 affect index use and performance in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL can use [any left portion of an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

In your example `SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE user_id = ?` will use the index but `SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE dated_on = ?` won't.

For a 3-column index A, B, C, `WHERE A = ? AND B = ?` will use an index over A and B, but `WHERE A = ? AND C = ?` will only use an index on A

Answer (score 5):

If your index on user_id and dated_on is really in that order (user_id first), then it will be used for a user_id query also.  You can check by using EXPLAIN to see the actual strategy for the query.

Comment: I'm actually interested to know how the seq_in_index value changes the query performance, so I've edited the question accordingly